# Select multiple files, "send to" batch.cmd, let batch.cmd run a program on selected files

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, sendto

I am using a converter on many files. Usually I just do it one by one but that takes time. I want to be able to select multiple files with CTRL+Lclick, right click, send to a batch.cmd that then runs this code:

```
"cmd /c dewssdos -P @file"
```

@file being one file from the "send to" list.

But I have no idea how to do it. I don't know how windows stores the list of files I just sent and how to access that list.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

This seems to be somehow related but I am a code noob and have no idea what to do here.

Can you guys help me out?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: the way to simulate right click action is vbscript/jscript -> shell.application ->invokeverb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you put several files with "send to" to a batch file, this batch file will receive a list of the file names. You can separate them quite easy:

```
for %%i in (%*) do echo %%i
```

`%*` stands for "all parameters"

**Edit** to your comments:

the variable `%%i` is only valid within a `for`context. This context ends with a NewLine. You have two possibilities to get around this:

a) set a variable (works only for first (or only) variable):

```
for %%i in (%*) do set var=%%i
REM %%i is not valid anymore here
echo %var%
D:\Spiele\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3 Tools\Audio\WAVToWSS.exe" %var%
DEL %var%
```

b) extend the `for`context:

```
for %%i in (%*) do (
    echo %%i
    if /i "%%~xi" == ".wav" D:\Spiele\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3 Tools\Audio\WAVToWSS.exe" %var% && del %%i
    if /i "%%~xi" == ".wss" D:\Spiele\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3 Tools\Audio\WAVToWSS.exe" %var% && del %%i
)
REM %%i is not valid anymore here
```

`&&` works as "if previous command was successful then". So the files should only be deleted, if the conversion was successful.

Comment: Thank you! Jesus christ, this saves me some HEADACHES!!! :D

Here is my final code:

for %%i in (%*) do cmd /c dewssdos -P %%i

Now I am lucky that dewssdos is "registered" with cmd, so I can easily run it.

What if I want to run a custom program on these files?

For example path to program is:
P:\Audio\WavToWss.exe 
and I want to use the parameter "-stereo".

How do I do that?

Thank you a TON so far, this is helping tremendously!

Comment: for %%i in (%*) do p:\Audio\WavToWss.exe %%i

Works fine, adding a parameter after it should work fine too, right?

Seems to... If I run into any problems, I will come back for help! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Hello,

is there a way to DELETE a file after it has been run through a program? I tried:

for %%i in (%*) do "D:\Spiele\Steam\SteamApps\common\Arma 3 Tools\Audio\WAVToWSS.exe" %%i
DEL %%i
PAUSE

but it tells me "%i could not be found".

I must be missing something here. I thought %%i means "file from that list". Why is it looking for "%i"?

Comment: I will take the 2nd veriant because the first one stops at the first loop.


Thank you so so so very much! You have made my live so much easier. :) Please, tell me where I can read up on such variables such as "%%i" etc.

Comment: ups - my failure. About %%i see `for /?`. Also search for "delayed expansion" here when you have trouble with variables inside a `for`context.

Comment: Ah nice, thank you! :) All of this is working tremendously well!!! My work flow is so fast now, thanks!

Is there a way to filter for *.wav and *.wss files in the command? So no other files than WSS and WAV are sent to the batch?

Thanks!

Comment: something like `if "%%~xi" ==".wav" echo %%i`? (see `for /?` for explanation)

Comment: Hello Stephan, thank you so very much again for this solution. This works great! I have a problem though - if I select TOO MANY objects, the script fails. The CMD window upens, remains empty for a split second but instantly closes again. This usually occurs with around 80-120 files. It seems to depend on the "size" of the list I send to the script.


For example: 
If I use folder structure:
c:\folder\sound.wav - I can "send to" a LOT more files compared to if I use:

c:\folder\veryLongFolder\AnotherLongFolder\AndAnotherFolder\sound.wav

Can you help?

Comment: @AndrejS. There is a limit, how many chars in a line can be handled. (not sure what it is. Somewhere a bit over 8000?) The longer the path, the less files. This is a limitation of `cmd.exe` and I know no way to break this limit. But maybe you can shorten the used path with `subst /?`

Comment: Thank you very much Stephan, I was afraid this was going to be an issue. The files are already on a rather short path. It's good to know that there is nothing more I can do. You really helped me out maximize the efficiency of this workflow. :) Thanks! I guess now I will have to either write a super advanced script (which I can't) or find someone to do it for me. :-/ Hahaha. But it won't be you, you helped enough. Thanks! :)